# Snmp community indexing string with snmpsharpnet library

Tags: snmp, snmpsharpnet

It is possible with the library in question (snmpSharpNet) to use a community indexing string, 
for example "public@x"

Comment: Libraries like snmpSharpNet are used to write SNMP managers (clients), so they of course allow you to use community indexing string. However, it would be the SNMP agent (server) side to support such and respond properly. Otherwise, you won't get what you want.

Comment: I'm converting an old project and with this new library, if I query the same device passing it as a community (public@x) error max try reached returns, while with the library of the old program it works without problems. Device is a cisco switch

Comment: Then capture packets using tools like Wireshark and compare. That should give you enough hints.